# Can these holomorhic functions $f:D(0,1)\to \mathbb{C}$ exist

Tags: complex-analysis

i)
$$
\begin{align}
\text{Let }f:D(0,1)\to \mathbb{C} \text{ holomorphic ,$\\$  Show that  }
 f(\frac{1}{n})\ne \frac{1}{n+1}
\end{align}
$$
for all natural numbers,except maybe for some finite cases.

I considered $\alpha_n=\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{\alpha_n}{\alpha_n +1}$ . Also $g(z)=f(z)- \frac{z}{z+1}$ and we can see that as $\alpha_n\to0, g(\alpha_n)=f(\alpha_n) +\frac{\alpha_n}{\alpha_n+1}=0$ , hence $f(z)=\frac{z}{z+1}$ by the identity theorem and this where I get stuck.

ii)
$$
\begin{align}
\\
\\
\text{Let }f:D(0,1)\to \mathbb{C} \text{ holomorphic }\\
 f(1-\frac{1}{n})=0 , \forall n= 1,2,..
\end{align}
$$

Can such a holomorphic $f$ exist?

I'm thinking that this would hold for $f\equiv0$

but taking $ 1-\frac{1}{n} \to 1 $ confuses me

Comment: Sorry, I've found a mistake, that answer was wrong

Comment: Now it's correct

Comment: Your solution for i) looks correct to me.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Don't I need to show a contradiction there to prove that there can't be such a holomorphic fuction?

Comment: But you have just shown one. Its pole is not in the open unit disc, so I see no problem. The question was *Can these holomorphic functions exist?*. I fear the answer is yes in case i).

Answer (score 2):

(ii) As you can see, main condition of identity theorem $\left(1\in D\right)$ does not hold. This can help us assume that not only $z=0$ is demanded function. If we remember Picard theorem, we conclude that $f$ can have essential singularity at $1$ and condition will hold. Indeed, 
$$f(z)=\sin \frac{\pi}{1-z} $$
satisfies conditions:
$$\sin \frac{\pi}{1-z}=0 \Leftrightarrow \frac{\pi}{1-z}=\pi k, k\in \mathbb{Z} \Leftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{1}{1-z}=k \Leftrightarrow 1-z=\frac{1}{k}, k\in \mathbb{Z}-0 \Leftrightarrow z = 1-\frac{1}{k}, k\in \mathbb{Z}$$
As $\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{Z}$, we have found non-zero corresponding function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! you're awesome